# return multiple objects from Django get

Tags: python, django, rest

I am updating an API get response in a Django app to include additional data. I have the following existing structure

`models.py`

```py
class OriginalModel(models.Model):
   field_1 = models.CharField()
   field_2 = models.CharField()
```

`serializers.py`

```py
class OriginalSerializer(serialisers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = models.OriginalModel
       fields = ['var_1', 'var_2']
```

`views.py`

```py
class OriginalView(RetrieveAPIView):
   query_set = models.OriginalModel.objects.all()
   serializer_class = serializers.OriginalSerializer
```

I now need to introduce an additional model (without updating the existing one), but have the view return all data from both models.

`models.py`

```py
class NewModel(models.Model):
   field_3 = models.CharField()
```

`serializer.py`

```py
class NewSerializer(serialisers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = models.NewModel
       fields = ['var_3']
```

What is the best way to update the view so that it can return the data from both models?

I have the following so far

`views.py`

```py
from rest_framework.response import Response


class OriginalView(RetrieveAPIView):
   query_set = models.OriginalModel.objects.all()
   
   def get(request, *args, **kwargs):
      original_model = get_object_or_none(models.OriginalModel, *args, **kwargs)
      s1 = serializer.get_serializer(original_model)

      new_model = get_object_or_none(models.NewModel, *args, **kwargs)
      s2 = serializer.get_serializer(new_model)

      if not s1 or not s2:
          raise Exception("Error getting models")

      return Response(s1.data)
```

Firstly, I am not sure if this is the correct approach? If so, I need help in extending the `query_set` variable to include the `NewModel` objects in addition to the `OriginalModel` ones. I also don't know how to correctly forumulate the response as a combination of two serializer `data` fields.

Comment: you can just combine results like `response_data={'original_model': s1.data, 'new_model': s2.data}` and `return Response(response_data)`